# Creating a Maven-like project documentation website with gradle

Tags: gradle

Maven provides a way to generate a project documentation site. Does Gradle provide a similar plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The only site plugin that I am aware of is [this one](https://github.com/breskeby/GradleSite). I personally I haven't tried it so I can't tell you about its feature set or quality.

Comment: Thanks, Benjamin. I haven't been able to try this out yet, but will report back once I do.

Comment: Maybe it's time to report about it now.

Comment: I started working on something else, and completely forgot about this question. I put some comments in a separate answer because I ran out of characters replying in the comment field.

Answer (score 0):

I had to move on to something else soon after commenting, then forgot about checking out the plugin Benjamin mentioned. I had a little time this evening so I looked at it. The plugin hasn't been updated in 3 years, so it appears abandoned/dead. I couldn't find a place to download the artifact, so I cloned the Git repo and built it.

I spent a little time trying to get it to work, but gave up. I looked around a little to see what else is out there. A couple of options that look promising are Gradle's TestReport task:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestReport.html

and the Gradle Site Plugin:

https://bitbucket.org/davidmc24/gradle-site-plugin

but I only played around with them for an hour and haven't used them in a real project.